# Can we delete the "cq6" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 6 questions taged with `cq6`. All of them also have the `cq5` tag. The product itself was called CQ (for Communiquée) until version 5, since version 6 it is called AEM (for [Adobe Experience Manager](http://www.adobe.com/ch_de/marketing-cloud/enterprise-content-management.html)) so there is no cq6 which makes this tag obsolete and confusing to a certain extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four of them already had the [aem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aem) tag, so I just removed cq6. For the other two, I removed cq6 and added aem. Since there are now no questions remaining with the cq6 tag, the roomba script should take care of it and remove it.